# .NET Azure Database Upload

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, azure

This is my connection string for my azure database:

```
Server=tcp:linkofy.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=Linkofy;Persist Security Info=False;User ID={your_username};Password={your_password};MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;
```

my .NET database connection string is:

```
Data Source=|DataDirectory|Linkofy-Release.sdf
```

In the Package/Publish SQL do I just add my azure connection string to the destination database with my username and password, will this upload my database to azure?

What would my web.config transformation connection string then be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would get the database up to Azure myself. I recommend you look into the [Data Migration Assistant.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/dma/dma-overview)

Once on Azure, you can use the [Azure App service App Settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-configure) to specify [the connection string](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/windows-azure-web-sites-how-application-strings-and-connection-strings-work/) your application should use instead of web.config transformations.

Comment: wow wonderful thank you this is a great direction, been looking at migration to sql server express and it was a really old guide and not helpful at all, just didn't know what to search will give this a go.

Comment: @Lucie No problem. Good luck.